# Quadratic in the form of matrix normals

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, symmetric-matrices, eigenfunctions

If I have a quadratic in the form $q(x y)=x^2+4xy+y^2$

and I want to express it in the form of normal coordinates.

This is what I've tried so far

$A$ s.t $(x y)A(x y)^T$ which is

A=$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 \\2 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

I find eigenvalues $\lambda =-1 ,\lambda =3 $ and eigenvectors

$v1=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $v2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

if I normalise my eigenvectors I get $v1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and
$v2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

my question is how would I express my original $q(xy)$ in terms of its normal coordinates.

Comment: Hint: You know that it’s going to be a sum of squares. Use the eigenvalues.

Comment: I have a few ideas. Would it be something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
-1,0 & \\ 0,3
 & 
\end{pmatrix}$
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$